# Trigger email send after cron job finished

Tags: email, cron

I have a `cron file` that contain this

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

MAILTO="myemail@gmail.com"
* * * * * php /home/forge/biossantibodies/artisan products:exportdiff --env=development
* * * * * php /home/forge/biossantibodies/artisan images:exportdiff --env=development
* * * * * php /home/forge/biossantibodies/artisan publications:exportdiff --env=development
* * * * * mailx -s "CronJob is run successfully" ben@gmail.com
```

I want it to send email to me after the cron job successfully ran.

I've tried:

```
MAILTO="myemail@gmail.com"
```

and:

```
* * * * * mailx -s "CronJob is run successfully" myemail@gmail.com
```

And I never received any emails, I looked in the spam folder as well, but I noticed the task between them work.

How would one go about configuring this?